# Another Tribond: What do these three have in common

Tags: tribond

Another tribond puzzle: find the unifying **theme** of these three things.

> Richard, Saturn, Redstone

***Note:*** The answer will be a connecting theme, having nothing to do with the makeup of the words themselves. No need to consider other possibilities, e.g. all words are proper nouns, or contain the letter "r".

Comment: To whoever downvoted: Downvoting is certainly your prerogative. I don't object to your downvote. But could you please leave some reason for the downvote, so that I can improve my puzzles in future? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I can see why. Having 2 first names out of the three makes it very broad indeed.

Comment: @Richard: The "tribond" puzzle type is generally easy to leave way too broad. (Personally, I think by themselves they should be disallowed, but that's a whole other issue.)

Comment: @Deusovi They may sometimes be too broad, but I don't think this one is. After all no one has yet suggested even one answer that fits all three.

Comment: @Matt how do you know they're first names? (hint, hint)

Comment: I've narrowed the question now. It shouldn't be too broad any more. Only problem is that it may be too easy now.

Comment: My problem is simply that there's too many possible non-answers.  All 3 words have an 'r'.  All three words have a vowel in the second letter.  All three words are proper nouns.  I could go on.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I'm sorry. I should have made it clear that the unifying theme has nothing to do with the words themselves, but what they mean. That is, the answer is nothing grammatical or phonetical. I will add this to the question.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha: I can't tell if this one is "too broad" or not.  But I disagree that it should be considered so only on the basis of commonalities that are trivial or uninteresting or way too obvious, which the creator quite clearly wouldn't have intended to be the answer.

Comment: I think I know the answer, even if it's too broad, but can't answer now.

Comment: I have an answer I want to add too! \**wiggles impatiently, waiting for reopen\**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's

> Rocket
>
>  [Maurice "The Rocket" Richard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Richard)
>
>  [Saturn V Rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V)
>
>  [Redstone Rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGM-11_Redstone)

Comment: seems to be correct, as it also matches the earlier versions of the question, where Roger and Clemens appeared in the third place instead of Redstone. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Clemens

Comment: Dangit, here I was waiting for a reopen, and you answered this first. ;_;

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : They are

> comic book characters/villains
>  [Richard The Warlock](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Richard_the_Warlock)
>  [Saturn Queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_Queen)
>  [Redstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redstone_%28comics%29)

Comment: upvote for giving a valid response, but not the one I was thinking of. Mine does not rely on specialized knowledge of comics.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the first two at least...

> Richard Wagner wrote The **Ring** of the Nibelung 
> Saturn is famously known as the **ringed planet**

I'm not sure about Roger tho.

Comment: Good guess, but no.

Comment: Also, "Rogering"

Comment: Rogers Jewelers